# How to change the tag itself in QueryPath?

Tags: php, querypath

I would like to change the tag itself, identified in QueryPath.  To be specific, I would like to convert an anchor tag like this
`<a href="abc.html">Example</a>`
into
`<?php Blah-Blah ?>Example</a>`
or
`<?php Blah-Blah2 ?>`

I can find the anchor tag and retrieve its element:
`$qp->find('a[href]'); $href = $qp->attr('href');`
but then, is there any way to change/replace the tag itself in QueryPath?

Alternatively it is fine by me to wrap the component with `<div id="specific">` tag - if this is possible, I suppose I can search for it with `$qp->top('div[id="specific"]');`, then can replace the entire child (the anchor tag and its element) with the php code.

However, I have failed to find either way in QueryPath...

Answer (score 4):

```
function renameTag( DOMElement $oldTag, $newTagName ) {
   $document = $oldTag->ownerDocument;

   $newTag = $document->createElement($newTagName);
   $oldTag->parentNode->replaceChild($newTag, $oldTag);

   foreach ($oldTag->attributes as $attribute) {
       $newTag->setAttribute($attribute->name, $attribute->value);
   }
   foreach (iterator_to_array($oldTag->childNodes) as $child) {
       $newTag->appendChild($oldTag->removeChild($child));
   }
   return $newTag;
}
```

and

```
$qp->find('a[href]')->each(function($index,$element){
   renameTag($element,'?php');
});
```

you have to iterate for all elements in the query ...

Comment: How do you create `$anchors` from a QueryPath object, say, `$qp`, which is created with, for example, `htmlqp($HtmlString)`?  I can find the particular anchor with `$qp->find('a[href]')` etc, but it is still a QueryPath object…

Comment: `$anchors = $qp->find('a[href]');`
i updated the answer

Comment: In PHP Ver.5.5.3, it raises an error `WD php: DOMException: Invalid Character Error in DOMDocument->createElement()`.  If I change `?php` into `p`, the result is as expected.  But it seems `?php` is not accepted for the function.  nb., I used the following to create `$qp`: `$qp = htmlqp('<html><head><title>none</title></head><body><p><a href="A">Example Anchor</a></p></body></html>');`

Comment: maybe you can use a costume tag name(eg:my_tagname) and then replace characters of the final generated string with '?php'

Comment: That may be possible, providing (1) one knows a tag name/word that would never appear anywhere else, (2) in replacing the tag with `?php`, it is possible to add other following PHP script (because otherwise it would also likely violate the rule enforced by the library), which may need use the attributes.  In fact, that is essentially what I did to solve this particular problem in the end (without using QueryPath, but by just text-processing)…  But your example and follow-ups were helpful enough for me to vote up.  Thank you!